# Div Above Navigation In Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I want div above menu bar hidden while we scroll down the page. Menu bar is shown while scrolling but div must be hidden.

Here is my code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default  navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class='col-md-12-fluid'>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class='clearfix'> </div>
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/kk.png"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home </a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="safety.html">Safety Trainings</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="dev.html">Development of HSE plan and Procedures</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="hse.html">HSE Consultation</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.contaenter code hereiner-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi you should hide the row containing the div above nav. I have created a working demo here http://www.bootply.com/KRFKQdd9Cz

**jQuery**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).on('scroll', function(){
        $('.container-fluid .col-md-12-fluid').eq(0).hide();
        console.log($(document).scrollTop());
//If you scroll to top of the page the search form shows again
        if($(document).scrollTop()==0){
          $('.container-fluid .col-md-12-fluid').eq(0).show();
        }
      });
    });
```